# How can I prefill my form based on a dropdown menu selection value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a form that has a dropdown selection menu that loads invoice ids from my database.  I'm trying to prefill my form based on the value of the invoice selected from the drop down menu.  In my database is a column "invoiceidcopy" which contains a value(s) that shows as a selection(s) for my drop down menu.  If you notice in my image of my database table below you will notice the first row/record's invoiceidcopy field is blank..in my drop down menu ...of course...the first selection is blank.  Ultimately my code below im trying to get to prefill my form works only when i select the blank selection from the drop down menu but not for the other 2 selections?  How can I prefill my form based on a dropdown menu selection value?

[image: DataBase]

**FORM**

```
<form action="#">

<select id="dropdown-select" name="dropdown-select">
<option value="">-- Select One --</option>
</select>

<button id="submit-id">Prefill Form</button>

<input id="txt1" name="txt1" type="text">
<input id="txt2" name="txt2" type="text">



<button id="submit-form" name="Submit-form" type="submit">Submit</button>


</form>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
     $(function(){


        $('#submit-id').on('click', function(e){  


            var invoiceidcopy = $('#dropdown-select').val();
            e.preventDefault(); 

             $.ajax({
              url: "/tst/orders2.php",
              data: {
                invoiceidcopy: invoiceidcopy
              }
            }).done(function(data) {

    data = JSON.parse(data);

$('#txt1').val(data.txt1);
$('#txt2').val(data.txt2);


});
        });
     });
</script>
```

**/tst/orders2.php**

```
<?php

// Create the connection to the database
$con=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");


// Check if the connection failed
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  die();
}

   if (isset($_GET['invoiceidcopy']))
{
    $invoiceidcopy= $_GET['invoiceidcopy'];

   $query = "SELECT txt1, txt2, q1
        FROM seguin_orders
  WHERE invoiceidcopy = '".($invoiceidcopy)."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
 echo json_encode($row);
 die(); 
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems the source of your error is from the json data you are sending to php via ajax. you should try enclosing the data key in quotes so that javascript will not replace it with the variable value.

```
   data: {
       'invoiceidcopy': invoiceidcopy
   }
```

Another possible source of your error is the sql to select the records from the table.
Have you tried removing the brackets from the variable name like so

```
 $query = "SELECT txt1, txt2, q1
        FROM seguin_orders
  WHERE invoiceidcopy = '".$invoiceidcopy."'";
```

or even using braces like

```
 $query = "SELECT txt1, txt2, q1
        FROM seguin_orders
  WHERE invoiceidcopy = {$invoiceidcopy}";
```

Also it will be good to check the value before it is sent to php just to be sure it is what you expect. For example you can do something like:

```
 e.preventDefault();
    var invoiceidcopy = $('#dropdown-select').val();
    alert(invoiceidcopy); /*display the value to confirm it is correct */
    // use the javascript console
    console.log(invoiceidcopy);
```

Comment: Okay. Be sure to provide feedback on the solution if you eventually find one.